# Pick only "name" from every entity from Core Data as Array Swift 4

Tags: arrays, core-data, swift4

I have User model and Car model in CoreData. I saved 3 cars for 1 user.

How can I pick only name variable of every car and set to an array?

```
    let users = try! managedContext.fetch(userFetch)

    let currentUser: User = users.first as! User
    let cars = currentUser.cars?.allObjects as! [Car]

    print(currentUser.email)
    let carsList = [String]
    cars.forEach { sample in
        carsList.append(sample.name)
    }
```

Is there a solution better than mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better solution

```
let carList = cars.map { $0.name }
```

And if you declare (and design) `cars` as non-optional `Set<Car>` rather than unspecified `NSSet?` there is a still better one

```
let currentUser = users.first as! User    
let carsList = currentUser.cars.map { $0.name }
```

No `allObjects`, no type cast

Comment: its an error:
"Value of type 'NSSet' has no member 'name'"

Comment: For the first solution you still need the line `let cars = currentUser.cars?.allObjects as! [Car]`. For the second solution please read my answer carefully.